# Округлить float после запятой

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть решение огромного примера = 2.0155429765245318e+54. Нужно округлить либо сократить до 3 знаков после запятой. Например - 2.015 или 2.016.
Format или round выдает бред. Кто что думает? Спасибо.

Comment: Если только для вывода, можно с помощью форматирования: `print(f'{x:.3e}')`, выведет `2.016e+54`. Может, это то, что Вам нужно? Просто странно округлять экспоненциальное число, выбросив степень, которая может различаться в зависимости от точности.

Comment: Это е+54 число 54 знака до запятой)) естественно раунд выдаст такое

Comment: ааа, вот я тупанул) думал 54 знака после идут, тогда все верно, спасибо

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

В свое время это использовал, просто измените немного как вам удоебней

```
def rd(x,y=0):
    ''' A classical mathematical rounding by Voznica '''
    m = int('1'+'0'*y) # multiplier - how many positions to the right
    q = x*m # shift to the right by multiplier
    c = int(q) # new number
    i = int( (q-c)*10 ) # indicator number on the right
    if i >= 5:
        c += 1
    return c/m
```

Сравните:
print( round(0.49), round(0.51), round(0.5), round(1.5), round(2.5), round(0.15,1)) # 0 1 0 2 2 0.1

print( rd(0.49), rd(0.51), rd(0.5), rd(1.5), rd(2.5), rd(0.15,1)) # 0 1 1 2 3 0.2

Comment: Спасибо, функцию сейчас попробую. А с round и format, он выдает нереально длинные числа, 30-ти  значные

Comment: да, еще решить данную проблему поможет модуль decimal.